# openvpn cli and dns leaks with systemd

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, openvpn, systemd-resolved

How do I make openvpn add the provider dns ?
I used to disable systemd-resolved to let resolvconf do it's work but now it totally unsupported by the network manager.
When I start the vpn with the gui it works, but via cmd line it leads to dns leaks even though I added up/down update-systemd-resolved.
The routing table is as follow when using the gui:

```
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
provider_dns     0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
provider_server _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlan0
...
```

also when using nmcli the dns shows up, but /etc/resolv.conf doesn't change.
it's linked to the "stub-resolver" in /run/systemd/resolve/.

What I want is launching openvpn from the command line. When I do so
the routes are as follow:

```
0.0.0.0         10.8.144.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         lan.home        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
10.8.144.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.144.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
184.75.221.114  lan.home        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
```

and nmcli is not showing the provider's dns.
I don't understand systemd-resolved at all and I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Actually the problem comes from the fact that Lubuntu just doesn't care about resolv.conf. I removed all entry in the file, it's till giving me access to the web. I'm removing the system now it's become trash, given the fact that is uses QT as a desktop environment proves that they'r more having a little fun than working for the community.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: it is the latest lubuntu, shipped whith lxqt. I think it's 19.04

Comment: It doesn't make a difference anyway, just tried with kali-linux it's still LEAKING